# UIImageView content mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

[image]

The blue line is the imageview's bounds.
`UIImageView`'s `contentMode` is `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`,
And I want keep the original picture's scale.
How can I make the picture's left edge is on the `UIImageView`'s left edge?
But not like `UIViewContentModeTopLeft` mode. Keep the scale and no blank in the left.
My english is not good, hope you guys could understand what I'm saying.
Thank you very much.

Comment: set your content mode As UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill ..

Answer (score 6):

```
 yourimageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
if ( yourimageView.bounds.size.width > yourimageView.size.width && yourimageView.bounds.size.height > yourimageView.size.height) {
   yourimageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

**Swift3**

```
yourimageView.contentMode = .center
if yourimageView.bounds.size.width > yourimageView.size.width && yourimageView.bounds.size.height > yourimageView.size.height {
yourimageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

you can change your mode as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewContentMode) {
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just like this

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
if (imageView.bounds.size.width > imageView.size.width && imageView.bounds.size.height > imageView.size.height) {
   imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the moment i saw your situation,i thought about this:

```
_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft | UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

and i tried it, but it makes things worse

so i think you may resize your imageView`s bound to fit the size you want with this code

```
/// resize image to fit in show area without changing image ratio
+ (CGSize)resizeImageViewFromImageSize:(CGSize)imageSize toFitShowSize:(CGSize)showSize {
CGFloat ratioW = imageSize.width / showSize.width;
CGFloat ratioH = imageSize.height / showSize.height;

CGFloat ratio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height;

if (ratioW > 1 && ratioH > 1) { 

    if (ratioW > ratioH) { 
        imageSize.width = showSize.width;
        imageSize.height = imageSize.width / ratio;
    } else {
        imageSize.height = showSize.height;
        imageSize.width = imageSize.height * ratio;
    }

} else if (ratioW > 1) {

    imageSize.width = showSize.width;
    imageSize.height = imageSize.width / ratio;

} else if (ratioH > 1) {

    imageSize.height = showSize.height;
    imageSize.width = imageSize.height * ratio;

} else {

    if (ratioW > ratioH) { 

        if (showSize.width / imageSize.width <= 2) {   
            imageSize.width = showSize.width;
            imageSize.height = imageSize.width / ratio;
        }

    } else {

        if (showSize.height / imageSize.height <= 2) {
            imageSize.height = showSize.height;
            imageSize.width = imageSize.height * ratio;
        }

    }

}

return imageSize;
}
```

then put your imageView align to left of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation



let originalsize = CGSizeMake(500, 500)
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)


var result = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(originalsize, rect)

print(result)
```